# Complex vector space of skew symmetric matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have been given a linear transformation $T,$ from the subspace $V\subset M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb C)$ of skew-symmetric matrices to $V,$ defined by$$\forall A\in V,\quad T(A)=BA-AB$$ where $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

So I took the standard ordered basis $E_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $E_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $E_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and found the Matrix of the linear transformation as:$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
of which the eigen values come out to be $\{0,i,-i\}$.

My question is what would be the eigen vectors corresponding to these eigen values (I got them all to be zero matrices, but by definition, eigen vectors cant be $0$)

Here are my calculations: After getting eigen values, I did like this: $MV=aV$
where $a$
is eigen value and $V$
is its eigen vector. So for $a
=0,$ I do this: $M \pmatrix{0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0} = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}
 ,$ so $\pmatrix{0&a&0\\-b&-c&0\\a&0&-c} = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$
and so comparing elements, $a=b=c=0$
Similarly for $a=i,-i.$

My further question is- Can there be eigen values without corresponding eigen vectors ?

Please help clarify

Comment: Can you please include your calculations? (of $M,$ and then of the eigen vectors) I think you made several mistakes. As for your last question, the answer is no, by definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval $T(E_1)=0$ so its linear combination wrt $E_1$,$E_2$,$E_3$ will be <0,0,0>. Similarly $T(E_2)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which gives coefficients as <0,0,-1> and finally $T(E_3)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which gives coefficient as <0,1,0>. Finally writing all the coefficients as column vectors I got the Matrix M.

Comment: Sorry and thank you. *I* first did mistakes in my calculation of $M$ but now I agree with you. $E_1$ is obviously an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0.$ The eigenvectors for $\pm i$ will be linear combination (with *complex* coefficients) of $E_2$ and $E_3.$

Comment: It looks to me like you correctly calculated the matrix $M$ and the eigenvalues. Your mistake must be after that. Remember, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if linear system $M-\lambda I = 0$ has non-trivial solutions. For example, you can easily see that $E_1 = (1\,0\,0)^t$ is eigenvector corresponding to $0$.

Comment: At the beginning of your post you take $V=M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb C)$ but later, you seem to take $V=$ the $3$-dimensional subspace of skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @Ennar Eigen vectors will be 3x3 skew symmetric matrices from the space rigth?

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry for the confusion; V is space of 3x3 skew symmetric matrices, I mentioned it indirectly while picking matrix A.

Comment: @AnneBauval could you show me how you figured out the eigen vectors by writing them explicitly

Comment: Yes, but if you work with matrix $M$ in basis $\{E_1, E_2,E_3\}$, then $E_1 = (1\, 0 \, 0)^t$, $E_2 = (0\, 1\, 0)^t$ and $E_3 = (0\, 0\, 1)^t$ when represented in that basis. Why don't you just show your work, I think I guessed what your problem is, but if you want an actual answer to your question, include all you have done.

Comment: Can you please edit your post, to 1) correct the definition of $V,$ 2) show us how you compute the eigenvectors?

Comment: @Ennar After getting eigen values, I did like this: $MV= aV$ where $a$ is eigen value and $V$ is its eigen vector. So for $a$=0, I do this:

$M \pmatrix{0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0} = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$

,so


$\pmatrix{0&a&0\\-b&-c&0\\a&0&-c} = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$

and so comparing elements, $a=b=c=0$

Similarly for $a$=$i$,$-i$

Comment: In $Mv=\lambda v$ the vector $v=aE_1+bE_2+cE_3$ must not be written as a $3\times3$ matrix but as the column matrix of its coordinates $a,b,c$ in the basis $(E_1,E_2,E_3),$ like you always do when you use the matrix of a linear trasformation $T$ in some basis to compute $T(v).$

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought the vector $V$ was from the original vector space. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Btw you still did not edit your post as required previously.

Comment: @AnneBauval done

Comment: Presumably all your basis vectors $E_j$ commute, your $M = E_3$ and so they will all commute. Are you sure you have the correct representation for $M$?

Comment: @asymptotic The $E_j$ do not commute; otherwise $M$ would be $0.$ The fact that $B=E_1$ makes the first column of $M$ equal to $0.$ The fact that $M=E_3$ is an irrelevant coincidence. Ennar and I already checked and agreed (in comments above) the OP's computation of $M.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, I follow, thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is mixing up what operator $T$ and matrix $M$ are and what they act on.

Operator $T\colon V\to V$ takes a vector $v\in V$ and produces vector $Tv\in V$. By choosing basis $\{E_1,E_2,E_3\}$ we can find unique matrix $M\in M_3(\mathbb C)$ such that $$TE_j = \sum_{i=1}^3 [ M]_{ij}E_i,\tag{1}$$ where $[M]_{ij}$ is a $(i,j)$-th matrix entry.

Since $M$ is in $M_3(\mathbb C)$ it doesn't make sense to write $Mv$ because matrix $M$ **doesn't care or know** what vector space $V$ is or **how it should act on it**. It's purely coincidental that $V\subseteq M_3(\mathbb C)$ so by writing $ME_i$ you didn't break any syntax, but there is no meaning to it related to your problem.

What $M$ **does know** is how to act on column-vectors, i.e. elements of $M_{31}(\mathbb C)$, by matrix multiplication. If $x\in M_{31}(\mathbb C)$, then $Mx\in M_{31}(\mathbb C)$ as well. So, via matrix multiplication, $M$ acts as if it were a function $M_{31}(\mathbb C)\to M_{31}(\mathbb C)$. Note how $V$ and $M_{31}(\mathbb C)$ have the same dimension.

Let me get back at $(1)$ because that formula is what establishes relation between $T\colon V\to V$ and $M\cdot(-)\colon M_{31}(\mathbb C)\to M_{31}(\mathbb C)$. Let $v = v_1 E_1 + v_2 E_2 + v_3 E_3\in V$. Then $\bar v = (v_1\, v_2\, v_3)^t\in M_{31}(\mathbb C)$. As we said, $Mv$ doesn't make sense, but $M\bar v$ does. If we calculate $M\bar v = (w_1\, w_2\, w_3)^t$, then we know that $Tv = w_1E_1+w_2E_2+w_3E_3$.

---

Now, to get back to calculating eigenvectors. What you are doing is calculating eigenvectors of $M$ which are column-vectors in $M_{31}(\mathbb C)$. Not in $V$, since remember that $M$ doesn't care or know what $V$ is.

By *definition* eigenvectors $x\in M_{31}(\mathbb C)$ of the matrix $M$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ are *non-trivial* solutions of the linear system $$(M-\lambda I)x = 0.$$

For eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$, you need to solve linear system $Mx = 0$. You can easily see that $x_0 = (1\,0\,0)^t$ is a solution. Since $M$ is of rank $2$, the solution space is $1$-dimensional and is spanned by $x_0$. So, that's, up to scalar, the only eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to $\lambda = 0$.

Now, since we have $Mx_0 = 0$, by the above discussion we know that $T(1\cdot E_1 + 0\cdot E_2 + 0\cdot E_3) = 0,$ so $E_1$ is the only eigenvector (up to a scalar) of $T$ corresponding to eigenvalue $0$.

In general, if $(v_1\ v_2\, v_3)^t$ is eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then $v = v_1E_1+v_2E_2+v_3E_3$ is eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$.

I leave the rest of calculations to you.

Comment: I appreciate the elaborate answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @санкетмхаске, you are welcome. Let me know if you'll still need help in determining the rest of the eigenvectors. You can check your solutions on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%7D). Of course, you still need to interpret these as vectors in $V$ as discussed in my answer.

Comment: I am glad you explained the concept in great detail. All this time, I was under the impression that-- for problems related to $R^n$ space, eigenvectors were the vectors of the input space! But now I realise that they are only coefficients. Even though in case of std basis the coeff would come out to be same as the vectors, but in any other basis it wont.

Comment: @санкет мхаске, I'm not sure if that's what you meant, but you can think of eigenvectors  of matrix $M\in M_n(K)$ as elements of $K^n$ or $M_{n1}(K)$ as I did here. Both $K^n$ and $M_{n1}(K)$ have canonical bases, so there is a canonical isomorphism between them (the obvious one) so it's not problematic to switch between them however you want. But yes, when you have some general vector space $V$, it's good to think of choice of basis just as coordinates and when you switch to matrix representation remember that you are just working with coordinates. (1/2)

Comment: You can try another problem if you want to reinforce the idea. Let's say that $V$ is the space of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$. Let $T(p(x)) = p'(x)+x p(1) - p(0)$. Determine eigenvectors of $T$. (2/2)

Comment: Or you can switch $-p(0)$ to $+p(0)$ for bit nicer numbers, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

I edit as an answer my comment, which turned out to be enough for you to understand and correct your mistake.

"In $Mv=λv$
the vector $v=aE_1+bE_2+cE_3$
must not be written as a $3×3$
matrix but as the column matrix of its coordinates $a,b,c$
in the basis $(E_1,E_2,E_3),$
like you always do when you use the matrix of a linear transformation $T$
in some basis to compute $T(v).$"

Comment: Thanks Anne for helping and editing. I struggled with the syntax  for matrices, symbols etc.